# Enviar mais de um projeto para um repositório no Github

Tags: github

Estou com um problema para enviar projetos separados para o mesmo repositório do Github.
Por exemplo: tenho uma pasta de exercícios de lógica de programação para enviar para meu repositório, esses desafios são separados por pastas, estrutura sequencial, condicional e etc.
A minha dúvida é como enviar esses projetos para um mesmo repositório.
Quando tento fazer um commit, recebo o erro abaixo:

$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/me/myproject
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/myproject'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Answer (score -2):

Você está tendo um erro de fetch-first, basicamente seu repositório remoto possui alterações que seu repositório local não tem.

Isso pode ocorrer por conta de você ter iniciado um repositório com a opção de "Adicionar README.md" do github, ou ter feito um fork de outro repositório com conteúdo já existente.

Nesses casos, você precisa primeiro fazer o git pull, para baixar tudo do repositório remoto e na sequência, fazer as alterações, criar um commit e fazer o push!

Mas se o seu repositório remoto for muito diferente do local, então você precisará seguir outra abordagem.

---

Para esclarecimento, seu erro é o seguinte (tradução livre):

```
erro: falha ao enviar algumas referências para 'https://github.com/me/myproject' 

dica: as atualizações foram rejeitadas porque o controle remoto contém trabalho que você não tem localmente. Isso geralmente é causado por outra alterações enviadas ao repositório: para a mesma referência.

Você pode querer primeiro baixar as alterações remotas: (por exemplo, 'git pull ...') antes de enviar novamente. 

dica: Veja a 'Nota sobre avanços rápidos' em 'git push --help' para detalhes.
```

Dê uma olhada nesse artigo sobre baixar as aterações remotas: https://docs.github.com/pt/get-started/using-git/getting-changes-from-a-remote-repository